# If input to InputBox does not equal value in range, then display msgbox and end sub

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Struggling with this.  I have an input box pop up.  The value entered is then searched for in a range of cells.  If found, it sets specific values.  However, I want it to display a msgbox and then end the sub if that value is not found in the range.  No matter what I try, I cannot get this to work.  If the code for the 'does not equal' is not there, it works fine so long as the value entered matches a value in the range.  When I add in the code for 'does not equal', it does launch the msgbox and ends the sub, but does so regardless of the value being found.  From what I can tell, it should be one or the other.  If it matches, it continues.  If not, it ends.  But that is not happening.  What do I have wrong here?  Thanks

```
Sub Test()
Dim aOutlook As Object
Dim aEmail As Object
Dim rngeAddresses As Range, rngeCell As Range, strRecipients As String
Dim strbox As String
Dim stritem As String
Dim x As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim lr, lookRng As Range
Dim findStr As String
Dim foundCell As Variant
Dim foundcell1 As Variant
Dim foundcell2 As Variant
Dim strbody As String
Dim sigstring As String
Dim signature As String
Dim findstr1 As String
Dim foundrng As Range
Dim findrange As String


Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0)


findstr1 = InputBox("Enter Email Address")
findStr = InputBox("Enter the name to find")

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
Set lookRng = Range("B1:B" & lr)

 For x = 1 To lr
    If Range("a" & x).Value = findStr Then
    Set foundCell = Range("B" & x).Offset(0, 4)
    Set foundcell1 = Range("B" & x).Offset(0, 1)
    Set foundcell2 = Range("B" & x).Offset(0, 5)
    End If
    Next x

   For r = 1 To lr
    If Range("a" & r).Value <> findStr Then
    MsgBox "Is case-sensitive", vbExclamation, "No Match!"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    Next r
```

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint on the line with the 'does not equal' and check what values are being compared? Do this for each step in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
Dim valueFound As Boolean
valueFound = False
For x = 1 To lr
    If Range("a" & x).Value = findStr Then
        Set foundCell = Range("B" & x).Offset(0, 4)
        Set foundcell1 = Range("B" & x).Offset(0, 1)
        Set foundcell2 = Range("B" & x).Offset(0, 5)
        valueFound = True
    End If
Next x

If Not valueFound Then
    MsgBox "Is case-sensitive", vbExclamation, "No Match!"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you PeterT! That did it, marked as answer!  Would you mind explaining to me what I was doing wrong?  Does the <> not work in this case?  What did the boolean do, and what did the valuefound property do?  Thank you again!

Comment: In your original code, you're using two different loops. The first one is finding ALL of the values in the range that match your `findStr`. Your second loop then rechecks all the same values to find one that doesn't match. Your second loop is unnecessary because you have all the information you need in a single loop. You just need a simple flag to keep track if you've found a match or not. So the `valueFound` variable (it's not a property) is a simple way to make a mark when you find a match.